# Rails Carrierwave + AWS Timing Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

In my Rails app, I generate a video file locally before saving it to Amazon S3 using the "generate_video" controller action in **spin_controller.rb**

```
  def generate_video
      // ffmpeg used to generate video at the path video_path (code omitted for clarity)

      # generate a new video model based  on this file
      video = Video.new(:spin_id => @spin.id, :video_file => File.open(video_path))
      video.save!

      respond_to do |format|
        format.html{
          redirect_to edit_project_path(@spin.project)
        }
        format.json{
          render :json => @spin.video.video_file_url
        }
      end
  end
```

The issue I'm running into is that if I call the "generate_video" action with a JSON request, the app tries to render the response before the Video model has completed saving.  The error I get in my logs is

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `video_file_url' for nil:NilClass)
```

referring to the format.json response.

Is there a way for the response to wait until the model has completed saving?

Comment: remove video.save! and try this `respond_to do |format| if video.save! format.html{ redirect_to edit_project_path(@spin.project) } format.json{ render :json => @spin.video.video_file_url } end end` i hope this will help you

Comment: good idea - unfortunately when I tested it, I received the same error.  I think the problem might have to do with how carrierwave saves to s3, perhaps in a background task?